# Lookup column display different value depend on value from another column in the same row inside dxdatagrid (Dev Extreme)

Tags: devextreme

I am using dxdatagrid in Dev Extreme library

Is there any way that I can filter data source of the lookup column right after change value of another lookup column in the same row inside the datagrid

I created this demo to explain:

```
var listAccount = [
    { ID: 1, WebsiteID: 1, Website: 'A', AccountID: '1', Username: 'A1' },
    { ID: 2, WebsiteID: 1, Website: 'A', AccountID: '2', Username: 'A2' },
    { ID: 3, WebsiteID: 2, Website: 'B', AccountID: '4', Username: 'B1' },
    { ID: 4, WebsiteID: 3, Website: 'C', AccountID: '7', Username: 'C1' },
    { ID: 5, WebsiteID: 4, Website: 'D', AccountID: '8', Username: 'D1' },
    { ID: 6, WebsiteID: 5, Website: 'E', AccountID: '9', Username: 'E1' }
];

var websites = [
   { WebsiteID: 1, Website: 'Website A' },
   { WebsiteID: 2, Website: 'Website B' },
   { WebsiteID: 3, Website: 'Website C' },
   { WebsiteID: 4, Website: 'Website D' },
   { WebsiteID: 5, Website: 'Website E' }
];

var account = [
   { AccountID: 1, Username: 'A1', WebsiteID: 1 },
   { AccountID: 2, Username: 'A2', WebsiteID: 1 },
   { AccountID: 3, Username: 'A3', WebsiteID: 1 },
   { AccountID: 4, Username: 'B1', WebsiteID: 2 },
   { AccountID: 5, Username: 'B2', WebsiteID: 2 },
   { AccountID: 6, Username: 'B3', WebsiteID: 2 },
   { AccountID: 7, Username: 'C1', WebsiteID: 3 },
   { AccountID: 8, Username: 'D1', WebsiteID: 4 },
   { AccountID: 9, Username: 'E1', WebsiteID: 5 },
   { AccountID: 10, Username: 'E2', WebsiteID: 5 }
];

var grid = $('#myGrid').dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: listAccount,
    columns: [
{
    dataField: 'ID'
},
{
    dataField: 'WebsiteID',
    caption: 'Website',
    lookup: {
        dataSource: websites,
        displayExpr: 'Website',
        valueExpr: 'WebsiteID',
    }
},
{
    dataField: 'AccountID',
    caption: 'Account',
    lookup: {
        dataSource: account,
        displayExpr: 'Username',
        valueExpr: 'AccountID',
    }
}],
    editing: {
        editMode: 'batch',
        editEnabled: true,
        insertEnabled: true
    }
}).dxDataGrid('instance');
```

On editing mode, is there any way when I select another website and the account only shows the account of selected website?
Eg: When I choose website A, only account A1 & A2 display in the lookup column

Comment: To filter dxDataGrid data by a value you can use the `filterRow` option. More information [here](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/filterRow/?version=15_1).

Comment: @Sergey thanks for response but I don't think it work in this case, the [link]filterRow[link] seem to work only with dxdatagrid datasource, in this case I need datasource in lookup change immediately depend on the value I change in another column in the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I suggest you use the [cellTemplate](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/?version=15_1#cellTemplate) and [editCellTemplate](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/?version=15_1#editCellTemplate) options. These options allow you to render the selectbox for the 'Website' column manually. Then, you will be able to handle value change of the WebsiteId using the `onValueChanged` option:

```
cellTemplate: function($cell, cellData){
    $cell.text('Website ' + cellData.data.Website);
},
editCellTemplate: function($cell, cellData){
    var $selectBox = $("<div>").dxSelectBox({
        dataSource: websites,
        displayExpr: 'Website',
        valueExpr: 'WebsiteID',
        value: cellData.data.WebsiteID,
        onValueChanged: function(){
            // filter your data here...
        }
    });

    $cell.append($selectBox);
}
```

The sample is here - http://jsfiddle.net/kb1681g0/2/

To filter data you can use the [DataSource.filter()](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Library/DataSource/Methods/?version=15_1#filter) method.

Hope this information will helpful.

Comment: Sorry for response lately. Here is mine onValueChanged handler:
onValueChanged: function(e){
             account.filter("WebsiteID", e.value);
                cellData.setValue(e.value)                
            }

But it seem nothing happen in account column

Comment: Try to filter data using `DevExpress.data.query().filter().toArray()`. See this http://jsfiddle.net/96orLbqs/